# Cant remove parent element of an element

Tags: jquery

My structure is:

```
<p>
        <span>
            <input type="text" class="key" value="21">
        </span>
        <span>   
            <input type="text" class="value" value="55">

        </span>
        <span>    
            <a href="#" class="updateAction" data-setting-id="1">update</a>
            <a href="#" class="deleteAction" data-setting-id="1">delete</a>
        </span>
    </p>
```

I try to remove the parent element like this whenever delete link is clicked:

```
 $(this).parent().parent().hide();
 $(this).closest('p').hide();
```

Comment: So, does that not work?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon because code mentioned is in `click` handler of `delete`.

Comment: hide doesn't remove anything.

Comment: That should work !...  try creating a fiddle --> http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: How are you binding the click event?  Is it in a document ready handler?

Comment: Works: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/2svGU/

Comment: @tymeJV `updateAction` deletes row. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/PHZxS/

Comment: @SachinG -- Bah, assigned the wrong click handler, you get the point :) haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close the input tags and call `preventDefault` and it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/P3tEw/

```
$(document).on("click", ".deleteAction", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('p').hide();
});
```

Comment: The two lines of code do the same thing so you might as well remove the `parent().parent()` version as it is slower.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".deleteAction").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.closest('p').fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $(this).remove();
   }); // with a fadeOut effect

});
```

[Check the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UW4Da/1/)